# WPF Application crash at start-up

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to start my application on another computer but when its starting it immediately crashes.

My application doesn't try to read a file while its starting up, but it still crashes with a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

I have no idea what to do about it, can anyone lend me some help with this?

This dumpfile was generated by with the application crash.

```
<WERReportMetadata>
<OSVersionInformation>
    <WindowsNTVersion>6.1</WindowsNTVersion>
    <Build>7600 </Build>
    <Product>(0x3): Windows 7 Home Premium</Product>
    <Edition>HomePremium</Edition>
    <BuildString>7600.16917.amd64fre.win7_gdr.111118-2330</BuildString>
    <Revision>1</Revision>
    <Flavor>Multiprocessor Free</Flavor>
    <Architecture>X64</Architecture>
    <LCID>1043</LCID>
</OSVersionInformation>
<ProblemSignatures>
    <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
    <Parameter0>bw000.exe</Parameter0>
    <Parameter1>0.9.1.0</Parameter1>
    <Parameter2>50461072</Parameter2>
    <Parameter3>PresentationFramework</Parameter3>
    <Parameter4>4.0.0.0</Parameter4>
    <Parameter5>4d930fa2</Parameter5>
    <Parameter6>9ef</Parameter6>
    <Parameter7>f</Parameter7>
    <Parameter8>System.IO.FileNotFoundException</Parameter8>
</ProblemSignatures>
<DynamicSignatures>
    <Parameter1>6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3</Parameter1>
    <Parameter2>1043</Parameter2>
    <Parameter22>0a9e</Parameter22>
    <Parameter23>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter23>
    <Parameter24>0a9e</Parameter24>
    <Parameter25>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter25>
</DynamicSignatures>
<SystemInformation>
    <MID>4F696B6F-82CF-4635-A6C8-BA2F7C68C6CA</MID>
    <SystemManufacturer>MICRO-STAR INTERNATIONAL CO., LTD</SystemManufacturer>
    <SystemProductName>MS-6657</SystemProductName>
    <BIOSVersion>V1.30</BIOSVersion>
</SystemInformation>
```

I checked my file in the release folder and PresentationFramework.dll is there.

**Update:**

I tried installing .NET Framework 3.5, it didn't run. I think its because i have .NET 4 installed.

I took the advice of Simon and looked in the Windows events log and found and stack trace of the error.

This is the situation now:

- I have an 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium to run the application on.
- The application is compiled as an 32-bit application.
- I have .Net 4 Extended and Client installed.
- I have set my main project and module project to run on .NET 4
- I have set an `DispatcherUnhandledException` but it isn't invoked, so it crashes before that.

so can anyone help me with this ?

This is the strack trace from the Windows Event logs:

```
Log Name: Application
Source:. NET Runtime
Date: 13/09/2012 9:12:51
Event ID: 1026
Task Category: None
Level: Error
Keywords: Classic
User: NA
Computer: PC-freedom
Description:
Application: BW000.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at BW000.App.OnStartup (System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   ate System.Windows.Application. <. ctor> b__1 (System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen (System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl ()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext (System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode (System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup (TryCode, Cleanup code, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke ()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue ()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation (System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen (System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage (System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run ()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher (System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal (System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run (System.Windows.Window)
   at BW000.App.Main ()
    
Event XML:
 <event Xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System>
     <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
     <EventID Qualifiers="0"> 1026 </ EventID>
     <level> 2 </ Level>
     <Task> 0 </ Task>
     <keywords> 0x80000000000000 </ Keywords>
     <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-09-13T07:12:51.000000000Z" />
     <EventRecordID> 525 </ EventRecordID>
     <channel> Application </ Channel>
     <computer> Freedom-PC </ Computer>
     <Security />
   </ System>
   <EventData>
   <Data> Application: BW000.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at BW000.App.OnStartup (System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   ate System.Windows.Application. <. ctor> b__1 (System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen (System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl ()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext (System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode (System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup (TryCode, Cleanup code, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke ()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue ()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation (System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen (System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage (System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run ()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher (System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal (System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run (System.Windows.Window)
   at BW000.App.Main ()
</ Data>
  </ Event Data>
</ Event>
```

Here some extra information that i found:

```
Log Name: Application
Source: Application Error
Date: 13/09/2012 9:12:52
Event ID: 1000
Task Category: (100)
Level: Error
Keywords: Classic
User: NA
Computer: PC-freedom
Description:
Name of application with error: BW000.exe, version: 0.1.0.0, time stamp: 0x504dfc8f
Name of module with error: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7bafa
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000b727
ID of process error: 0xf90
Start time of application with error: 0x01cd917f300ba4e0
Path to application with error: C: \ Users \ freedom \ AppData \ Roaming \ Boomerweb \ Boomerweb Platform \ App \ BW000.exe
Path to module with error: C: \ Windows \ syswow64 \ KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 6e2030c0-fd72-11e1-9968-406186e5690b
Event XML:
<event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System>
     <Provider Name="Application Error" />
     <EventID Qualifiers="0"> 1000 </ EventID>
     <level> 2 </ Level>
     <Task> 100 </ Task>
     <keywords> 0x80000000000000 </ Keywords>
     <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-09-13T07:12:52.000000000Z" />
     <EventRecordID> 526 </ EventRecordID>
     <channel> Application </ Channel>
     <computer> Freedom-PC </ Computer>
     <Security />
   </ System>
   <EventData>
     <Data> BW000.exe </ Data>
     <Data> 0.1.0.0 </ Data>
     <Data> 504dfc8f </ Data>
     <Data> KERNELBASE.dll </ Data>
     <Data> 6.1.7601.17514 </ Data>
     <Data> 4ce7bafa </ Data>
     <Data> E0434352 </ Data>
     <Data> 0000b727 </ Data>
     <Data> F90 </ Data>
     <Data> 01cd917f300ba4e0 </ Data>
     <Data> C: \ Users \ freedom \ AppData \ Roaming \ Boomerweb \ Boomerweb Platform \ App \ BW000.exe </ Data>
     <Data> C: \ Windows \ syswow64 \ KERNELBASE.dll </ Data>
     <Data> 6e2030c0-fd72-11e1-9968-406186e5690b </ Data>
   </ Event Data>
</ Event>
```

Comment: Does the "other" computer have the correct .Net framework installed?

Comment: Does the Windows event log show anything? Often you'll get a stack trace with an entry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for this late response, the problem was not in .NET but an Microsoft Redistributable that wasn't installed.

Thank for your responses.

Comment: Which microsoft redistributable?

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable.

Comment: For setup and deployment projects add a merge module to the dependencies for example Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x86.msm

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the client computer has the same version of the .NET Framework that you used to create the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can install on your machine WPF Framework

On this you have 3.5 Version with Service Pack 1

Link : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22

If you want just download assembly (PresentationFramework.dll or others ) :

Link : http://www.search-dll.com/dll-files/download/presentationframework.dll.html